# Java - Parsing exception for some specific dates

Tags: java

I'm using SimpleDateFormat to parse dates.. And I've detected that some "valid" dates are causing exceptions.

Example that works fine:

```
    @Test
    public void testThatWorksFine() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
        dateFormat.setLenient( false );
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse( "2006-11-22 00:00:00" );
        assertNotNull( parsedDate );
    }
```

Test with error:

```
    @Test
    public void testThatDoesntWork() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
        dateFormat.setLenient( false );
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse( "2010-10-17 00:00:00" );
        assertNotNull( parsedDate );
    }
```

Result: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2010-10-17 00:00:00"`

Important: I need to disable lenient because I want to raise error when my date String is invalid, but, in the second test the date is valid and the parse doesn't works..

Any idea why the date `2010-10-17 00:00:00` results in error when I try to parse?
When I increse or decrease 1 day (`2010-10-16 00:00:00` or `2010-10-18 00:00:00`) it works..

Obs about env.: Running Java version 1.8

Comment: Parses fine in Java 11 and 8 for me.

Comment: Works fine for me as well in Java8. In any case, it's better to use the `java.time.xxx` classes since the antique `Date` class is error prone.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo / @DevilsHnd - thanks for your answers! I found the problem.. Actually the date `2010-10-17 00:00:00` isn't valid because of the 'daylight saving time' for Brazilian timezone :/
So, the Java's bahaviour is't wrong..

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Since the date and time in combination is not valid because of summer time (DST), does that mean that you *do* want the exception?

Comment: @OleV.V. well, in this specific case (DST) I don't want error and I workaround my code to increse 1 hour (2010-10-17 00:00:00 => 2010-10-17 01:00:00), but, I need to use LENIENT=FALSE because of other reasons.. For example, If I don't use LENIENT=FALSE the parser won't raise error for a grotesque invalid date.. Example, `9-99-9999 99:99:99` will work.. About my workaround (+1hr), I know it doesn't sound good but it was my only option, I'm consuming an API that returns this "invalid date" and fixing the API is out of my league..

Comment: In this case java.time offers a very fine solution for you: `LocalDateTime.parse("2010-10-17 00:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))`. Yields `2010-10-17T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]`. Substitute the Brazilian time zone you intended, as you know, there are several.